# Battery life of a MSI

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery

I have an MSI Creator 15 A10UET-222NL that I have had for about 3 years. For some time now, I have been experiencing the problem that the battery life of my laptop is only about 1.5 hours without the power supply, while I am not doing any heavy work on it. Now, I read somewhere that the orange light on the power button means that your dgpu is being used, or something else, but I have no idea what that process could possibly be. Does anyone have any possible ideas how I could extend the duration?

Comment: Have you had the laptop plugged in all time?  If so are you using Battery Threshold management?

Comment: 1. Check the power plans. 2. *If* the battery is still good, but the API needs to be reset, see https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Recalibrating+laptop+batteries/101517

Comment: @John sorry for the late response, but I have indeed in my powersettings limited the capacity of my battery to 60% when I am behind it all day.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I'll check it, thank you!